# .Netcore webapi iun vs2019 run, but command window is full of exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In vs2109, I debug the webapi, and it works, but on out deployed server it doesn't', i wasn't to fix all the exceptions that occur in the command window when the webapi is starting up and running in the debugger..

It looks to be 2 basic excpetions, It can't find CMD even though C:\windows\system32, and something with vueclimiddleware...

Anyone else get these? I"m stuck as to how to fix them.

My next guess is creating an empty api to compare.

Content root path: D:\TFS\StudentPortal4Api_1_1\StudentPortal4Api
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'cmd'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'cmd' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\sybase15_7\DBISQL\bin;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p64;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;**C:\Windows\system32;**C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\ely.glenn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PocketBuilder 2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.))
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'cmd'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'cmd' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\sybase15_7\DBISQL\bin;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p64;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\ely.glenn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PocketBuilder 2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'cmd'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'cmd' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\sybase15_7\DBISQL\bin;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p64;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\ely.glenn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PocketBuilder 2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at VueCliMiddleware.ScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at VueCliMiddleware.ScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at VueCliMiddleware.ScriptRunner..ctor(String workingDirectory, String scriptName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 envVars, ScriptRunnerType runner) at VueCliMiddleware.VueCliMiddleware.StartVueCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger, Int32 portNumber, ScriptRunnerType runner, String regex) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at VueCliMiddleware.VueCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__3_0(Task`1 task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at VueCliMiddleware.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'cmd'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'cmd' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\sybase15_7\DBISQL\bin;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p64;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\ely.glenn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PocketBuilder 2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.))
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'cmd'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'cmd' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\sybase15_7\DBISQL\bin;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p64;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\ely.glenn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PocketBuilder 2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'cmd'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'cmd' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\sybase15_7\DBISQL\bin;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess64\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p64;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Users\ely.glenn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\drivers;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\Sybase Central 4.3\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PocketBuilder 2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Brown.ericw.dotnet\tools
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at VueCliMiddleware.ScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at VueCliMiddleware.ScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at VueCliMiddleware.ScriptRunner..ctor(String workingDirectory, String scriptName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 envVars, ScriptRunnerType runner) at VueCliMiddleware.VueCliMiddleware.StartVueCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger, Int32 portNumber, ScriptRunnerType runner, String regex) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at VueCliMiddleware.VueCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__3_0(Task`1 task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at VueCliMiddleware.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 0):

> The directory name is invalid
> ...
> at VueCliMiddleware.VueCliMiddleware.StartVueCliServerAsync(String sourcePath

The cmd/path stuff is a generic warning; it's the invalid directory that's the real problem. The SourcePath you've provided to  VueCLieMiddleware doesn't exist or can't be accessed.  Look for a MapToVueCliProxy call and fix the SourcePath used.